# Convert SimpleStringProperty to String?

Tags: java, javafx, prepared-statement

I'm using simple string properties in JavaFX, which I need as I cannot change strings within action events.
In my SQL I'm using a String variable, in a prepared statement, to search any table. This variable is used to get data out of the correct table.

Can I Change a simple string property into a string or is there another way I can use the simple string property in my SQL statement.

E.G

THIS IS WORKING CODE IF I GAVE A STRING

```
StringVariable = String
```

But I have a simplestringproperty

So mine would be

```
StringVariable = SimpleStringProperty
```

Which doesent work.

```
PreparedStatement = " SELECT ?.* " .... further SQL statemet

PreparedStatement.setString(1, StringVariable);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just get the value of the property with

```
stringVariable.get()
```

Comment: Thanks, i see that it's stupidly simple. I'm new to all this so thanks! I was looking at how to convert a string property to a string and nothing came up so i just panicked.